# IE 10 Missing border segments while printing table elements

Tags: printing, border, internet-explorer-10

So I've been dealing with an issue with printing table elements in IE 10 only, where portions of the border will be missing/cutoff. The weird part is that looks to be only the first row of the tbody, and only the first and last cells of that row are affected.

Here some of the things I have found so far:

1. The table on screen looks just fine, but only when printing will the borders be missing.
2. I get the same behavior in Standards and Quirks mode.
3. It looks like it is a combination of using border-collapse, borders on both cells and the table elements, and using thead/tbody. If I remove any of these parts, the borders will re-appear and everything looks as they should.

Here's a test page that I wrote that shows the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        table {
                border-collapse: collapse; 
                 border: 2px solid black;
        }

        td {
                border: 1px solid black;
        }

        th {
                border: 1px solid black;
        }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Champion</th>
          <th>Note</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
              <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>UI Team Meeting</td>
        <td>3/5/2013 1:00 PM</td>
        <td>User Interface</td>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>PM Meeting</td>
        <td>3/4/2013 10:00 AM</td>
        <td>PMs</td>
        <td>Jane Doe</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
              </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

So has anyone else seen this before and has found a solution? I haven't even been able to find anyone else talking about this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I came across a similar issue in IE 9. The top half of the border on the first row of the first table on a page would not appear on the paper version of the page. When I load your code I see the same symptom.

I worked around our problem by combining the border rules for the `table`, `th`, and `td` into a single rule. The trick appears to work for yours as well, but it means the outer border will be the same size as the inner border:

```
    table {
            border-collapse: collapse; 
    }

    table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, we came up with a similar solution, but it seems to only work if you use 1px as the border width. Anything larger still shows the same problem. But we will probably get by with just using a 1px border. On the bright side, MS has acknowledged this bug and "is looking into it". https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/771188/tables-printing-problem-in-ie10

Comment: Same issue in Chromium browser. Works like a charm! :)