# IE10 Border Issue w/ Rowspan while printing

Tags: html, printing, border, internet-explorer-10, html-table

Can anyone explain why when printing from IE10, the borders in the following HTML table will not be displayed on the print-out?

Even if you don't have an answer, has anyone else noticed this behavior?

I've been printing to Microsoft XPS Viewer, but it also does not display when printing to a printer.

Here's a similar IE10 print issue, but it's not quite the problem I'm experiencing:
[IE 10 Missing border segments while printing table elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750134/ie-10-missing-border-segments-while-printing-table-elements)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Broken IE10 Print Page</title>
    <style>
    table {
        border: 3px solid black;
        font-size: 8pt;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    th {
        padding: 2px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    td {
        padding: 2px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width: 975px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>        
                <th>Test1</th>
                <th>Test2</th>
                <th>Test3</th>
                <th>Test4</th>
                <th>Test5</th>
                <th>Test6</th>
                <th>Test7</th>      
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">
                    Broken in Print
                </td>
                <td>Material</td>
                <td>Material</td>
                <td>0.10000</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>            
                <td>Rowspan 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Material</td>
                <td>Supplies</td>
                <td>0.20000</td>
                <td>0.1</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td>Manual</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Test123</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>0.00000</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td></td>            
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good luck with this. My own experiences in developing print stylesheets is that print behaviour is very poorly documented.

Comment: The Internet Explorer Team responded on Microsoft Connect. They are able to reproduce my issue and are investigating it. https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/797783/ie10-border-issue-with-rowspan-while-printing

Comment: Do not use 'px' for borders use 'pt' or 'em'

Comment: Microsoft responded saying that they've fixed the issue in the latest version of Internet Explorer (IE11). I guess there is no hope for IE10.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to IE > Tools [alt+x] > print > page setup. In the upper left corner, you should see *Paper Options*. Under that, there is a checkbox titled *Print Background Colors and Images*. Try printing after enabling that.

Answer (score 0):

Despite Microsoft's response, I'm still seeing this problem in IE 11 when
my document goes over one page.  But I have found a hacky work around.

Remove the rowspan, and any cell that should have had a row span can
now have its contents in a span with `position: absolute;`.  Then it's
just a matter of using css to remove what shouldn't be there.  If you
can also use `table { border-collapse: collapse; }`, you can't even
see the break.  Here's a complete example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>IE11 Table</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 3ex;
  }
  td.rowspan {
    border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;
  }
  td.rowspan span {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -1.5ex;
  }
  td.rowspanned {
    border-top: 0 solid transparent;
    color: transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tbody>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>E1</td><td>E2</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="rowspan"><span>F1<br>F1A<br>F1B<br>F1C<br>F1D</span></td><td>F2</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="rowspanned">G1</td><td>G2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>H1</td><td>H2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>I1</td><td>I2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>J1</td><td>J2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>K1</td><td>K2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>L1</td><td>L2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>M1</td><td>M2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>N1</td><td>N2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>O1</td><td>O2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>P1</td><td>P2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Q1</td><td>Q2</td></tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3ex;
}
td.rowspan {
  border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;
}
td.rowspan span {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -1.5ex;
}
td.rowspanned {
  border-top: 0 solid transparent;
  color: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>C1</td><td>C2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>D1</td><td>D2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>E1</td><td>E2</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="rowspan"><span>F1<br>F1A<br>F1B<br>F1C<br>F1D</span></td><td>F2</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="rowspanned">G1</td><td>G2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>H1</td><td>H2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>I1</td><td>I2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>J1</td><td>J2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>K1</td><td>K2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>L1</td><td>L2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>M1</td><td>M2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>N1</td><td>N2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>O1</td><td>O2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>P1</td><td>P2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Q1</td><td>Q2</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```